# 301 Redirect .htaccess more than 90 Pages Redirect

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^product\-page$ "http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/product\-page\.html" [R=301,L]
```

As there are around 100 Product pages in store. Anyone can get me effective way for redirecting all the www.domain.com/product-pages to www.domain.com/product-pages.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear really how you want the redirect to be, but you should be able to use something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1.html [R=301,L]
```